# Using plink to connect unix servers to run a script through a batch file

Tags: unix, batch-file, windows-8, putty

I have create a batch file on my desktop (script.bat) with the below script

```
@echo off
set /p id="Enter Unix Login ID: " %=% 
set /p pwd="Enter Password: " %=% 
cls
del jobInfo_error.txt

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=\n" %%G IN (Apps_list.txt) DO ( plink -l %id% -pw %pwd% "%%G "/export/home/user/collection_fail.ksh " 2>>JobInfo_error.txt )
GOTO :eof

start notepad JobInfo_error.txt
```

Here Apps_list.txt contains the list of servers. Something like:

```
server1
server2
...
...
etc
```

It was working fine when I had Windows XP. I was recently migrated to Windows 8 and now I am not able to run it.

The error is:

```
Plink error: Remote command failed
(Exit code 1)
```

Comment: please be more specific about "im not able to run it", by editing your question (and NOT responding in comments ;-) ).  Does a basic use of plink from the command line work? Do you get any error messages? If you remove the @echo off, do all of the commands seem to be working as correctly? Good luck.

Comment: removed @echo off.... no luck and yes basic command was working until the migaration

Comment: OK, I hope you didn't think removing `@echo off` was going to solve the problem. BUT you do have the helpful error message now `ERROR: Plink error: Remote command failed (Exit code 1)`. So that is what you have to focus on. Why is plink failing? Most likely that you need to login manually to the remote machine (using `ssh`) and reply `yes` to the ssh prompt for `Connecting to unknown server, is this OK (yes/no)` (Similar to this, I don't know the exact text). Also that's all I can offer on this question. Typically this sort of problem requires someone that can come to you desk to help.